# regexp to wrap a line with ${color} and $color

Tags: regex, sed

Is there a way to have this regex put ${color orange} at the beginning, and $color at the end of the line where the date is found?

```
DJS=`date +%_d`;
cat thisweek.txt | sed s/"\(^\|[^0-9]\)$DJS"'\b'/'\1${color orange}'"$DJS"'$color'/
```

With this expression I get this:

`Saturday Aug 13   12pm - 9pm      4pm - 5pm

Sunday Aug 14        9:30am - 6pm    1pm - 2pm

Monday Aug 15        6:30pm - 11:30pm None

Tuesday Aug 16       6pm - 11pm      None

Wednesday Aug 17    Not Currently Scheduled for This Day

Thursday Aug ${color orange}18$color     Not Currently Scheduled for This Day

Friday Aug 19        7am - 3:30pm    10:30am - 11:30am`

What I want to have is this:

`Saturday Aug 13      12pm - 9pm  4pm - 5pm                                       Sunday Aug 14        9:30am - 6pm    1pm - 2pm

Monday Aug 15        6:30pm - 11:30pm None

Tuesday Aug 16       6pm - 11pm      None

Wednesday Aug 17    Not Currently Scheduled for This Day

${color orange}Thursday Aug 18     Not Currently Scheduled for This Day$color

Friday Aug 19        7am - 3:30pm    10:30am - 11:30am`

Comment: You basically have it nailed; if this doesn't work for you, I suspect it's because of incompatible regex constructs -- I don't think I have seen a `sed` which groks \b for example. Also, lose the Useless Use of Cat.

Comment: Re the edit: Ah. Well, that wasn't too easy to know from the question as originally phrased ;) I'll update my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Acually, it works for me. Depending on your version of `sed`, you might need to pass `-r`. Also, as tripleee says, don't use `cat` here</strike>

```
DJS=`date +%_d`
sed -r s/"\(^\|[^0-9]\)$DJS"'\b'/'\1${color orange}'"$DJS"'$color'/ thisweek.txt
```

**EDIT:** Ok, so with the new information I arrived at this:

```
sed -r "s/([^0-9]+19.+)/\${color orange}\1\$color/" thisweek.txt
```

This gives me the output

```
Saturday Aug 13 12pm - 9pm 4pm - 5pm
Sunday Aug 14 9:30am - 6pm 1pm - 2pm
Monday Aug 15 6:30pm - 11:30pm None
Tuesday Aug 16 6pm - 11pm None
Wednesday Aug 17 Not Currently Scheduled for This Day
Thursday Aug 18 Not Currently Scheduled for This Day
${color orange}Friday Aug 19 7am - 3:30pm 10:30am - 11:30am $color
```

(Note that it differs from your's since it's friday at least in my time zone)